# Access linked list items from a vector of references to those items

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, doubly-linked-list

I have a vector of integers, and I need to perform a lot of moving, chopping, and changing on that list.  But... I will primarily need to access those items by what their value is.

So what I've cooked up is an idea to use a std::list (double-linked-list) which will facilitate the re-ordering operations.  Then to also create a vector indexed by the integer values, where the values are vectors of references to the std:: list items.   That way I do not have to iterate the entire linked list to find a particular value in the list, as I will have these smaller vectors of references.

I can't figure out how to set this up though.

Here is a sample of what I've tried to do:

```
vector<int> original = { 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0 };
vector<vector<int*>> byNumber(4);
list<int> linkedList;
for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); ++i) {
    linkedList.push_back(original[i]);
    byNumber[original[i]].push_back(*linkedList[i]);
}
```

Pushing the 'original' items into the linkedList is easy enough, but then creating the reference in byNumber is where I'm stuck on.  I've tried pushing in `&(*linkedList[i])` too.  I'm not clear on what syntax I can use to do this, and whether it will even be possible.  I've also dabbled with unique_ptr instead of int* which I may switch back to if this is too problematic.

Comment: `int*` is not a reference to a list item. You may want to store *iterators*.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the advice to use an iterator I came up with this.  But if anyone has a tighter solution I'd love to hear it.

```
vector<int> original = { 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0 };
vector<vector<list<int>::iterator>> byNumber(4);
list<int> linkedList;
list<int>::iterator it;
for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); ++i) {
    linkedList.push_back(original[i]);
    it = linkedList.begin();
    advance(it, i);
    byNumber[original[i]].push_back(it);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
vector<vector<int*>> byNumber(4);
```

you are storing pointers, not references. You could do that, by doing this:

```
vector<vector<int&>> byNumber(4);
```

But why not storing iterators, like this:

```
vector<vector<vector<int>::iterator>> byNumber(4);
```

Comment: You're right, I got confused.  Thanks for pointing that out.  The actual line I really need advice about is:  byNumber[original[i]].push_back(??); and can you elaborate on the iterator idea?  For example, what are the pros over references, and do you know of the performance differences?

Comment: @braks I think I am confused by your design, sorry!

Comment: Oh okay :(  Thanks for trying.